# Goal not executed during clean lifecycle

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I developed a maven plugin to install the missing jars that cannot be found in central repository but can be found in local file system,i attach the goal to pre-clean phase and when i execute command "mvn clean compile", the plugin is not executed, instead i got the following error:

[image]

i suppose the missing jar in the error is installed firstly and then compile phase is executed. However, the error indicates dependency should be resolved firstly.

**PS:**
here is the config of my plugin in pom.xml:

[image]

Comment: Add code and stacktrace as text not as link

Comment: First why have you developed an Maven plugin to install jars? Furthermore you should use a repository manager and install the missing jars there afterwards you can use them as usual dependencies. Apart from that maven-install-plugin and maven-deploy-plugin exist already? And please code/stacktract as text into the question not as link or image...

Comment: firstly, i developed the plugin to install the 3rd party dependencies at one time automatically, rather than install them one by one. Secondly, both the plugins you mentioned exist. Regarding to the last advice, i'll past the code as text in the future(this time is for privacy), thanks.